# TOCTTOU code vulnerability

Tags: security

I have a piece of code in C, and I need to know where I have the TOCTTOU vulnerability and why. Does somebody know where it is and how I can correct it?

```
int process(char *filename)
{
    struct stat aux;
    char buffer[1024];

    printf("Input to be appended: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    if((lstat(filename, &aux) == 0) && !S_ISLNK(aux.st_mode))
    {
        printf("[+] Opening\n", filename);
        int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_APPEND), nb;
        nb = write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        printf("[+] Done!\n");
        return 0;
    }else
        printf("[-] ERROR\n", filename);

    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    return process(argv[1]);
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The use of lstat() provides a TOCTOU vulnerability because the file may be deleted after the lstat() and before the open(). Use open() instead and test the return value is a simple solution for this.

Comment: can you give me an example in the code please? thanks! :)

Comment: Surely you're joking, mr. user7346822 ;-)

Comment: nope, if i see what you mean i will understand it better. Thanks

Comment: Instead of the lstat test use : if ((fd = open(...)) != -1) { ...}. Declare the 'int fd' first, remove the open() from within the if block. Note that the S_ISLNK() test is a TOCTOU issue too but is not needed anyway.